# What is the origin of 'Just Kidding'?

Tags: expressions

The phrase is quite popular but I wish to know its origin. Is it possible that it has something to do with childbirth (also called kidding)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to come from ‘make a kid of,' according to the Oxford English Dictionary.

When I kid you, I am using your innocence (a childlike quality) to fool you, or perhaps I am treating you like a child.

Comment: +1 as I had no idea. I always assumed it came from behaving like a kid, as in I am joking around so I'm acting like a kid.

Answer (score 0):

Kid is also slang for a child. So: "kidding me" could have come from "being childish with someone" or "Lying to someone" or "Childishly joking with someone" in a sense.

-Look! There's an elephant right behind you!
-*person turns around*
-Just kidding!